# Memory Leak: Downloading a file with Node JS in Linux causes a memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, v8, node-ffi

I am using node.js (v0.10.22) and express module and providing download files functionality to the users.
We are downloading an average of 50 files per request averaging about 700 MB in size. 
We have our own C program which writes these files at run time and child process which send these files to the users in synchronously.

We are using FFI module to call C functions . The problem I am facing is that node.js increases virtual memory also it doesn't release significant amount of memory used & after some download gets `ENOMEM` error & crashed .My PC H/W configuration is 1 GHZ single core proc and 512 MB RAM. The question here is why V8 not releasing memory after each request OR is there any special kind of compilation required for node / V8. We have tested our c programs with Valgrind and it did not show any memory leak.

```
async.series([
  function DecryptFile(cb) {
    logger.debug("call decrypting Function for========="+param);
    var childProc = cp.fork(__dirname + '/child.js');

    childProc.on('message', function(m) {
    logger.debug('PARENT got message:', m.timestamp);
    decFile=m.timestamp;
    if(decFile){
      if(bluetoothReq){
        res.send(conf.get('contentTempFile')+decFile+"/"+ fName);
        return;
      }else{
        logger.debug("downloading for device : "+param);
        var folderPath=conf.get('contentTempFile')+decFile;
        var downloadPath = path.join(folderPath, fName);
        stats = fs.lstatSync(downloadPath);
        if(stats.isFile()) {
          res.download(downloadPath,fName, function(err){
          if (err) {
            // handle error, keep in mind the response may be partially-sent
            // so check res.headerSent
            logger.debug("res Error :");
            console.log("res Error :");
          } else {
            // decrement a download credit etc
            logger.debug("res Successfull :");
            console.log("res Successfull :");
          }
          logger.debug("res on End :");
          rmdir(folderPath, function(error){
          logger.debug("content download Succefully :"+downloadPath);
          console.log("delete Folder Successfull :"+downloadPath);
          if(error){
            logger.debug('rm -rf '+folderPath);
            exec('rm -rf '+folderPath);
          }
       });
     });
   }
  }
  }else{
    statsLogger.addStats(req,statsCode.TYPE_ERROR_DOWNLOAD,contentId,content.title+"-"+fileName);
    res.send("1,Problem while Downloading ");
  }
  childProc.kill();
  });
  childProc.send({ filePath : folderName+ fileName,
  temp      : conf.get('contentTempFile'),
  timestamp : timestamp,
  fName     : fName });
```

Comment: Take a look at this well-written article on NodeJS memory leak debug: http://www.joyent.com/blog/walmart-node-js-memory-leak

Comment: Show us some code. It is possible to create memory leaks with node, but without any information about the code, it  is very hard to answer.

Comment: i have updated question please see my code.